# jQuery - Animate then hide

Tags: jquery

In jQuery how can I animate an element then hide it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/fs1rnydc/15/)

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500).slideUp(400);
});
```

Comment: What do you need exactly ? The code does what you tell it to do. Within 500ms the element gets animated to opacity 0 and then slided up :)

Comment: Is the opacity: 0 the same as hide? I want to apply display: none; to the element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fs1rnydc/18/ use callback

Comment: No. Opacity 0 is compareable to visibility:hidden; which means it s not visible but still physically in the DOM.
slide up changes the style of it to display none after its animation is done

Comment: @noa-dev: You meant `visibility: hidden;`, not `display`.

Comment: Can I apply visibility: hidden then display: none?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) callback function.

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).hide(); // applies display: none; to the element .panel
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the complete parameter of jquerys animate function

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function(){
        $(this).hide(); //alt $(this).slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. However the slideUp is not working =(

Comment: No, but I think I know what's wrong. Actually I need to apply slideUp to the next .panel div and not to the current one that's been hidden.

Comment: Okay, doesnt get clear from the code snippets you have provided