# jQuery hide/show are only instantaneous, how can I make them transition with my carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-carousel

I'm pretty new to code and programming, but I'm playing around to learn some tools for web development. I've tried to make a bootstrap carousel trigger a change in text beside it and succeeded (see code below). But I also want it to have the same transition property as the carousel, which is a 1.5s fade out and in. However, I can only make the div (with the different text) appear and disappear instantaneously. If I add any jQuery fade() or slide() it will act as if I'm pressing a link to the carousel-ID.

This is the code I have for triggering hide/show for the div. I began with just the top part of the script, but played around with the second to see if I could get a different result.

```
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event){
    let image = (event.to);
    if (image == 1)  {
      $("#header-1").hide();
      $("#header-3").hide();
    }
    else if (image == 2)  {
      $("#header-1").hide();
      $("#header-2").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#header-2").hide();
      $("#header-3").hide();
    }
  });
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").on('slid.bs.carousel', function(event){
    let image = (event.to);
    if (image == 1)  {
      $("#header-2").show();
    }
    else if (image == 2)  {
      $("#header-3").show();
    }
    else {
      $("#header-1").show();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Animate then hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696175/jquery-animate-then-hide)

Comment: Question is a little confusing, please clarify what you want to happen and what happens with your code and why it's not what you want.  At the moment you have "*have the same transition*" / "*if I add fade() it acts as if I'm pressing a link*"

Comment: [`show` has an overload that takes a duration and a callback that fires when complete](https://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete). The jQuery API documentation is actually pretty good...

Comment: This is how it looks on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2p78eo4s/

I want the text to have the same transition (fade) as the carousel. However, if I add .fade() it won't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another link for the jQuery and that seems to have resolved the issue :)!

Edit:
Previous jQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
New and working jQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js

The script now looks like this and works smoothly.

```
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event){
let image = (event.to);
if (image == 1)  {
  $("#header-1").fadeOut(500, function() {
  $("#header-2").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $("#header-3").hide();
}
else if (image == 2)  {
  $("#header-1").hide();
  $("#header-2").fadeOut(500, function() {
  $("#header-3").fadeIn(500);
  });
}
else {
  $("#header-2").hide()
  $("#header-3").fadeOut(500, function() {
  $("#header-1").fadeIn(500);
  });
}
```

});

Comment: Can you post the link you used and a short code snippet that shows what worked please? This will allow this question/answer to be helpful to future visitors who may have the same problem.